# How to draw two box plots horizontally and at the same height in one figure?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have two `1x5` vectors as follows.

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5]
B=[7 8 9 10 11]
```

Note that their entry values have no overlapping at all. I wish to have **two box plots** that lie horizontally at the same height of the y-axis, i.e. **side by side**, in one figure.

I learn that

```
x = rand(5,1);
y = rand(10,1);
z = rand(15,1);
group = [repmat({'First'}, 5, 1); repmat({'Second'}, 10, 1); repmat({'Third'}, 15, 1)];
boxplot([x;y;z], group, 'orientation', 'horizontal')
```

is able to draw three box plots together in one figure. However, the three box plots lie on three different y-axis "levels".

How may I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `position` property:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5];
B = [7 8 9 10 11];


group = [repmat({'First'}, 5, 1); repmat({'Second'}, 5, 1)];
         boxplot([A';B'], group, 'orientation', 'horizontal','positions',[1 1])
```

As you can see, the y-labels are screwed up and manual labeling is required.

[image]

... which is quite easy to solve by just substituting `{'Second'}` with `{' '}`. You could use [annotations](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) instead for manual labeling.

```
group = [repmat({'boxplots'}, 5, 1); repmat({' '}, 5, 1)];
         boxplot([A';B'], group, 'orientation', 'horizontal','positions',[1 1])
annotation('textbox', [0.35,0.8,0.07,0.06],...
           'String', 'First','LineStyle','none');
annotation('textbox', [0.7,0.8,0.11,0.06],...
           'String', 'Second','LineStyle','none');
```

[image]